# Xamarin UI Automation with Appium - Setting JAVA_HOME on MacBook Pro - appium-doctor Does Not Sees It

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, appium, java-home

I am trying to set JAVA_HOME at my MacBookPro for Xamarin Android UI Automation using Appium.

I think I have set it up correctly.  Below, it shows its setting in my .bash_profile file and the output of JAVA_HOME in terminal, however, running appium_doctor says that JAVA_HOME is not set up

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

figured it out by setting path to bin in my bash_profile right below setting JAVA_HOME line  in bash_profile visible in screenshot above

```
#
# set JAVA_HOME/bin so appian_doctor does not complain
#
export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH
```

this solved my problem